# Странный роутинг в kohana3

Tags: php, kohana-3, маршрутизация

Приветствую вас. Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой: `kohana3`, судя по поведению, в нетрезвом состоянии, так как при правильно заданном маршруте для роутера выскакивает ошибочка:

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL signup was not found on this server.
```

Маршрут написан по мануалу в точности.

```
Route::set('assest', '<action>',
    array(
        'action' => '(login|signup|logout)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Assest'
    ));
```

.htaccess стандартный, изменения не вносились.

Вот такие вот странности, знает кто, как лечить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снова моя не внимательность, не обратил внимание на строчку из документации, так как она написано очень мелким шрифтом, которая гласит, что маршрут должен быть задан до стандартного :D